# How to use Entity Reference and Views

Tags: entities, views

Been reading a lot of questions and playing around alot and I haven't been able to figure this out.

I have a node with a field for entity references.  I'm trying to make a view that I can put on the node page that will grab the fields I want from the referenced entities but I haven't been able to make this happen.

I've created a view that that gets the current NID and I've set up relationships to the entity reference field on the node.  I've also created a node with a the reference field filled out and in the views preview I'm passing that NID, but nothing is returned.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why the view isn't returning the referenced entities that I've defined on the specific node?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use the relationship on the filters as well.

[image]