# How to create a view showing content linked with an entity reference field?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have 2 content types: Developments and Carousel Images. Carousel Images has an entity reference field to select the Developments page it is linked to.

I simply want to create a view which will display on all Development pages, but only show the images which are linked to it. So the Development page called 'London' will display a view with all Carousel images where 'London' is selected in the entity reference field.

I have tried using contextual filters and relationships but not been able to get this working.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32510/how-to-use-entity-reference-and-views - in short it's possible, it's just a little complex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did look at this, but it seems to be more to do with showing content in a view from linked content types. I'll check again in case I missed something but what I want is to dynamically link the content of a view to display in a block in a different content type based on.a link through possibly an entity reference fiield.

Comment: OK, finally worked out how to do it. Thanks to this video which explains it all: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Pdii7aFIvc&t=392s
However, in case anyone else is stuck you need to first create a relationship based on your entity reference field, sthen create a contextual filter using node:id based on url. This is all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally worked out how to do it. Thanks to this video which explains it all: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Pdii7aFIvc&t=392s
However, in case anyone else is stuck you need to first create a relationship based on your entity reference field, sthen create a contextual filter using node:id based on url. This is all you need to do.